# What is the best practice to load ScriptableObjects to single prefab/multiple prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(ScriptableObject = SO)

I've recently been trying to learn about ScriptableObjects and have set up a project in Unity where I simply want to shoot incoming enemies that spawn. I have set it up so I can create different enemies through the SO:s but noticed that I still need to create a prefab for every single enemy. Therefore after not much luck googling I wanted to ask if there is a way to load in specific SO:s for every enemy spawned?

Say I have a spawnmanager that is spawning different enemies depending on their % to spawn. Is it possible in run-time through scripts check the probability for which enemy to spawn and then load/find that specific data created through SO:s?

Comment: you can have a manager that will hold a list of SO's, or have an SO that supports generating different enemies on demand, theres tons of ways

Comment: sounds a bit broad .. what about simply having a list of SO references or a Dictionary in the class responsible for the spawning? As it sounds however I would prefer to have a component on the Prefabs themselves and reference according SO there as you want every prefab being related to a specific SO right?

Comment: @derHugo I was thinking that one prefab could work if possible because every enemy is basically the same with identical components but with different stats from the ScriptableObjects.

Comment: Yes as I said use a List e.g. I don't know how your scripts works since you didn't provide any code example ;)

Answer (score 3):

TLDR : use Monobehvaiour to implement an enemy. Use SO just to setup its data or to implement part of its logic. So it's better not to spawn one SO per enemy. You spawn enemy as prefab and in their prefab you may add one or more SO to achieve composition.

To understand this I can explain the history of the SO, so you can find all the usual implementations.

### **Phase 1 - Data Container**

Initially SO was made to store (non mutable) data. They could work as TEMPLATES.

IE, you have one Weapon SO and you instantiate it one for each weapon.
In this way you can just attach the weapon to an unit.

```
    public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Weapon weapon;

        public void Attack(IDamageGetter target) => target.GetDamage(weapon.damage);
    }

    public interface IDamageGetter
    {
       void GetDamage(int Damage);
    }

    [CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Base Weapon")]
    public class Weapon : ScriptableObject
    {
        public int damage = 5;
    }
```

Some nice tutorials about SO used for data are these:
[Customising UI With Scriptable Objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkUSmI7F304)

### **Phase 2 - SO Logic for composition**

After phase 1, [someone noted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vmRwLYWNRo) that SO may be used for many different things.
So many developers started adding logic inside the SO.

```
    public class AttackerWithLogic : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public WeaponWithLogic weapon;

        public void Attack(IDamageGetter target) => weapon.Attack(target);
    }

    public abstract class WeaponWithLogic : ScriptableObject
    {
        public int damage = 5;

        public abstract void Attack(IDamageGetter target);
    }
```

Doing so you can decouple a great deal of logic from the monobehaviour and attach any logic on the SO itself.
You won't have one monobehaviour enemy with 2 derived class enemyWithAxe and enemyWithSword.
You will have one Monobehaviour enemy and you may attach weaponAxe or weaponSword.

A great source to understand this logic and apply event to AI is this series of tutorials.
[Pluggable Ai With Scriptable Objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHUXh5biQMg)

### **Phase 3 - Reactive Scriptable Objects**

And in the end we had this new way of using Scriptable objects described at [Unite Austin 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk).

This is more advanced that the other ideas, and requires to understand the Observer pattern and the C# event system, but it is a great way to use scriptable objects.

This might be used as spawner.

```
    [CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "EnemySpawner")]
    public class EnemySpawner : ScriptableObject
    {
        public event Action<Enemy> OnSpawn;

        public Enemy enemyPrefab;

        public void SpawnEnemyWithSword()
        {
            var enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab);
            //..
            //code to setup sword 
            //..
            OnSpawn?.Invoke(enemy);
        }

        public void SpawnEnemyWithAxe()
        {
            //any other logic with the same event
        }
    }
```

SO are great to implement OOP pattern I'm still not sure what will be their future with the new ECS, but I hope there will be a place for them too.

**In Conclusion**

I'm a great fan of SO, but there are a few cases where you want to spawn one SO for enemy. And anyway SO shouldn't replace MonoBehaviours everywhere. I would use a MonoBehaviour to represent an enemy.

If you still need to have one SO for each monobehaviour you may create them with ScrictableObject.CreateInstance at awake, but in this case they won't be much different from a base serializable class.

Still you may implement SO to setup its data (such as health or weapon damage), to handle part of its logic (such as adding effect to each weapon), or to handle the event of the spawn mechanics.
I strongly suggest to give a look at the links I shared here. Choose where to start based on your experience, Phase 1 videos are the easier while Phase 3 are the most advanced. (Anyway all of them are easy enough, only the last one requires to understand the **event** of c#)

Comment: Sorry for my vague question. I solved it by creating a prefab for my melee and ranged enemies each with their corresponding Monobehaviour scripts inheriting from one base enemy class. Then when I spawn an enemy I have a couple of lists of different enemies that I put into the spawned enemy prefab depending on which enemy I want to spawn, which currently is just randomized from the list but going forward I want to have different % chance for each enemy to spawn. Thanks for the answer though! I will check out your links so I can learn more about this!